# Mobile view for section looks weird

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm having trouble figuring out mobile view layout problem. When I view my site via mobile, the section shrinks accordingly instead of showing full width image and stacked. How do I fix it so that the boxes sit above each other when viewed via mobile? I am using Bootstrap.

[image: Desktop]

[image: Mobile]

```
<section class="health" id="health">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="section-title st-center">
                            <h3>Places to exercise</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid">
                            <figure class="portfolio-item">
                                <img src="images/eastcoastpark.jpg" alt="east coast park"/>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h2>Nice <span>Lily</span></h2>
                                    <p>Lily likes to play with crayons and pencils</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <figure class="portfolio-item">
                                <img src="images/eastcoastpark.jpg" alt="east coast park"/>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h2><span>EAST COAST PARK</span></h2>
                                    <p>Long stretch of running and cycling/skating paths, it’s one of Singapore’s best spots to go jogging or bike riding.</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <figure class="portfolio-item">
                                <img src="images/eastcoastpark.jpg" alt="east coast park"/>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h2>Nice <span>Lily</span></h2>
                                    <p>Lily likes to play with crayons and pencils</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <figure class="portfolio-item">
                                <img src="images/eastcoastpark.jpg" alt="east coast park"/>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h2>Nice <span>Lily</span></h2>
                                    <p>Lily likes to play with crayons and pencils</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <figure class="portfolio-item">
                                <img src="images/eastcoastpark.jpg" alt="east coast park"/>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h2>Nice <span>Lily</span></h2>
                                    <p>Lily likes to play with crayons and pencils</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <figure class="portfolio-item">
                                <img src="images/eastcoastpark.jpg" alt="east coast park"/>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h2>Nice <span>Lily</span></h2>
                                    <p>Lily likes to play with crayons and pencils</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: .health {
  padding: 2em;
}
.grid figure {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.grid figure img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

Comment: Eer, thanks for including your CSS, but please add it into the actual question text, and not as a comment - some people won't read this far, and comments can be lost very easily.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you gave the figure or any other element the picture is nested in a fixed hieght, you can fix in css that with `height: auto;`

Comment: Hi, I've used 100% for max height. Changed it to auto but still shows the same error.     .grid figure {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.grid figure img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  }

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do this would be to look at adding col-span to each of the images for example, using col-span-4 on three images would allow them to stack nicely against each other in desktop but then in mobile view they would automatically drop under each other due to the default css

```
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/gallery/1.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/gallery/2.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/gallery/3.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/gallery/4.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
```